# Insert cell value using column name and row count - Using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for a function where i will pass the column header name, row count and the value as its parameters. The function should insert the cell value in the expected column and row location.

Or as a start let me know how to update a cell using column name and row count. Currently i have a 2d array that has column name and its value. I also have an integer variable that has the row location and total column count. Not sure how to use column name and row count together to insert the value.

Kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: where you want to insert? is it in grid?

Comment: excel sheet..in a table (which is already there in another sheet with some existing values)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Indirect()`

`=Indirect("A"&count("A:A"))`

Or you can use `Index()` (better, since it is not volatile)

`=Index("A:A",count("A:A"))`

The `Count` function will work if the data is numeric. If it is not, use `CountA` instead.

Comment: any idea how to add this function using vba ?

Comment: somethinling like `[b1].Value = "=Indirect(""A""&count(A:A))"` (there may be a small typo above in teylyn's answer)

Comment: fixed typo in Index formula. Thanks @brettdj.